Ubuntu 20.04.6 suddenly turns all icons grey and crashes immediately
Ubuntu 20.04.6 suddenly turns all icons grey and crashes immediately.  I think this is due to hardware or filesystem issues with the NVMe drive.
Sometimes I get Authentication error at the lock screen.
I use the following applications majorly:

PyCharm for remote development.
Chrome browser for YouTube, ChatGPT, Gemini
Terminal for SSH to server.

When this crash occurs, it first strucks Chrome. Then all icons turn grey except PyCharm's icon, as seen in the following screenshot:

I asked fsck manually check /dev/nvme0n1p5 for errors. It checked it and I got the message that File system was modified (this repeats). I have also tried sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, even then, suddenly, the icons turn gray and the system crashes. I also reinstalled Chrome with sudo apt install --reinstall google-chrome-stable, but still the same issue.
Please note that the issue is repeatable after reboot.
After reboot, I ran journalctl -b | grep -i gnome and collected the error and failed messages:
gnome-session-binary[1056]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: 
Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation

Error creating FIFO: File exists

cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed

Running sudo badblocks -v  /dev/nvme0n1p5 showed that there are 8 bad blocks.
$ sudo smartctl -H  /dev/nvme0n1p5
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1p5
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0       1000     5  0x7134  0x4502  0x000    975030992     1     -
  1        999     0  0xa01b  0x4004      -            0     0     -

$ journalctl --since "2024-11-08 13:40" --until "2024-11-08 13:41" -k
-- No entries -- 

But From Nov 05, I see the following error in journalctl:
Nov 05 22:26:19 Tara-desktop kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 121747290, async page read

other block too: 121908226

The recent logs when the issue occurred:
Nov 09 22:26:34 Tara-desktop kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 121747290, async page read
Nov 09 22:26:34 Tara-desktop kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 121747290, async page read
Nov 09 22:26:34 Tara-desktop kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 121747290, async page read
Nov 09 22:26:34 Tara-desktop kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 121747290, async page read

...

Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop avahi-daemon[757]: Interface eno1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop NetworkManager[764]: <info>  [1731158835.5697] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop whoopsie[1262]: [22:27:15] offline
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1033]: dbus-daemon[1033]: [session uid=126 pid=1033] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.10' (uid=126 pid=1146 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1033]: dbus-daemon[1033]: [session uid=126 pid=1033] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:15 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

...

Nov 09 22:27:31 Tara-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1033]: dbus-daemon[1033]: [session uid=126 pid=1033] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.10' (uid=126 pid=1146 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Nov 09 22:27:31 Tara-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1033]: dbus-daemon[1033]: [session uid=126 pid=1033] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:31 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:31 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:31 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 09 22:27:31 Tara-desktop gsd-sharing[1146]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

I reinstalled the followings. Still the issue reoccurs.
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 systemd dbus
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

I got EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5) and I run the following.
sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/nvme0n1p5

Welcome to ASK. You need to edit your question and add a lot more information. Firstly, what led up to this crash? What do you think might have caused it? What you were running. Is it repeatable after a reboot? You should take a look at the logs and post anything that looks like it might be the cause to you question. Try running the following after rebooting from an event putting the times before and after accordingly 'journalctl --since "2024-11-08 13:40" --until "2024-11-08 13:41" -k' then same remove -k and add -p emerg..err

Try sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^

Thank you so much for your reply.  I have edited my question. Kindly please check.
